# Como fazer vários inserts simultâneos com php

Tags: php, mysql

Eu preciso percorrer um json e pegar os valores e insertar no banco mas acho que seria uma péssima ideia colocar um insert dentro de um loop.

Gostaria de saber como fazer vários inserts simultâneos com php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatene os INSERTs com `;` ou faça o INSERT da seguinte maneira:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(coluna1, coluna2, coluna3)
VALUES
     (valor1, valor2, valor3),
     (valor4, valor5, valor6),
     (valor7, valor8, valor9) ...
```

Comment: Exatamente esta resposta Silvio Andorinha! :-)

Comment: O que mais recomendo é fazer o insert em multiplas linhas como @rodrigorigotti comentou pelo motivo de o processamento no banco ser muito mais rápido.

Comment: Exemplo do manual do mysql: INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);